# insert even if the row before is empty

Tags: excel, vba

i have this form in a sheet and it has a command button with a macro.
When i click it it will insert all the data in the Sheet1 cells in a single row in sheet2.
i've put the next empty row command, but i want that all the data still in the same row, even if the previous row is empty.

i've used the following code:

```
    Sub Botao()
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim código, tipo, textobrevematerial, codigopa, textobrevepa, ncm, versão, motivo1, motivo2, motivo3, datarecebimento, _
        dataimpressao, datamkt, datarevisor, datasedev, dataar, datart, dataredmkt, dataredsedev As Range

        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Plan1")
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("Plan2")
        Set código = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)
        Set datarecebimento = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)
        Set tipo = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp)
        Set textobrevematerial = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp)
        Set codigopa = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp)
        Set textobrevepa = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp)
        Set ncm = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "g").End(xlUp)
        Set versão = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp)
        Set dataimpressão = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "i").End(xlUp)
        Set datamkt = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp)
        Set datarevisor = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "k").End(xlUp)
        Set datasedev = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "l").End(xlUp)
        Set dataar = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "m").End(xlUp)
        Set datart = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "n").End(xlUp)
        Set motivo1 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "o").End(xlUp)
        Set motivo2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "p").End(xlUp)
        Set motivo3 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "q").End(xlUp)
        Set dataremkt = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "r").End(xlUp)
        Set dataresedev = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "s").End(xlUp)

            código.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("d4").Value
            datarecebimento.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("H4")
            tipo.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("b8")
            textobrevematerial.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("D8")
            codigopa.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("B12")
            textobrevepa.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("D12")
            ncm.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("B16")
            versão.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("D16")
            dataimpressão.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("F18")
            datamkt.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("F20")
            datarevisor.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("F22")
            datasedev.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("M18")
            dataar.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("M20")
            datart.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("m22")
            motivo1.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("B26")
            motivo2.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("B30")
            motivo3.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("B32")
            dataremkt.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("F38")
            dataresedev.Offset(1, 0) = ws1.Range("M38")

    End Sub
```

so what code should i use to insert all in the same row even if the previous row contains a empty cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This exact code works for me in Excel:

```
Sub Botao()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rowNum As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Plan1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Plan2")
rowNum = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row 'Get last used row in column A
rowNum = rowNum + 1 'Increment to next open row

Dim código, tipo, textobrevematerial, codigopa, textobrevepa, ncm, versão, motivo1, motivo2, motivo3, datarecebimento, _
dataimpressao, datamkt, datarevisor, datasedev, dataar, datart, dataredmkt, dataredsedev As Range

'Use next open row of column A (rowNum) for all columns
Set código = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "a")
Set datarecebimento = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "b")
Set tipo = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "c")
Set textobrevematerial = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "d")
Set codigopa = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "e")
Set textobrevepa = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "f")
Set ncm = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "g")
Set versão = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "h")
Set dataimpressão = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "i")
Set datamkt = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "j")
Set datarevisor = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "k")
Set datasedev = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "l")
Set dataar = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "m")
Set datart = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "n")
Set motivo1 = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "o")
Set motivo2 = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "p")
Set motivo3 = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "q")
Set dataremkt = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "r")
Set dataresedev = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "s")

'----------Checking for duplicate in column A---------
Dim bool As Boolean
bool = False                  'Initialize False, until duplicate is found

For i = 1 To (rowNum - 1)     'Go through each row of column A except the new row
    If ws1.Range("d4") = ws2.Cells(i, "a") Then  'If it matches any old row set boolean True
        bool = True
    End If
Next i

If bool = True Then           'If duplicate was found, display MsgBox
    Dim msg As String
    Dim title As String
    Dim ret As Integer
    msg = "There is a duplicate in column A"
    title = "Duplicate!"

    ret = MsgBox(msg, vbOKOnly, title) 'MsgBox(Promt, Button(s), Title)
'----------Done checking for duplicate-------------
Else                          'If no duplicate found, insert new row
    'Set values
    código.Value = ws1.Range("d4")
    datarecebimento.Value = ws1.Range("H4")
    tipo.Value = ws1.Range("b8")
    textobrevematerial.Value = ws1.Range("D8")
    codigopa.Value = ws1.Range("B12")
    textobrevepa.Value = ws1.Range("D12")
    ncm.Value = ws1.Range("B16")
    versão.Value = ws1.Range("D16")
    dataimpressão.Value = ws1.Range("F18")
    datamkt.Value = ws1.Range("F20")
    datarevisor.Value = ws1.Range("F22")
    datasedev.Value = ws1.Range("M18")
    dataar.Value = ws1.Range("M20")
    datart.Value = ws1.Range("m22")
    motivo1.Value = ws1.Range("B26")
    motivo2.Value = ws1.Range("B30")
    motivo3.Value = ws1.Range("B32")
    dataremkt.Value = ws1.Range("F38")
    dataresedev.Value = ws1.Range("M38")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it not working at all, or is it just not doing what you want?

Comment: if i use the code as you sent and put the rowNum = ws2.cell... before the set ws1 = worksheet ... it highlight and gives me error in the rowNum = ws2.cell... code line

Comment: if i put it after set ws1 = worksheet ... it gives me error in Set codigo = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "a").Select code line

Comment: You need to make sure it is located after you `Set ws1 =` and `Set ws2 =` because it references both of them. Otherwise, ws1 and ws2 will not have defined worksheets. I changed the code, the `rowNum` definition should be after ws1 and ws2, that was my mistake.

Comment: after that change it returns the error in Set codigo = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "a").Select code line

Comment: Alright, I actually went into Excel and the code in my answer works for me in Excel for your scenario (assuming I understood correctly). Obviously I only used the first 3 columns, but if you add the rest in just like that it should work.

Comment: I made one more edit, and it should include all of your original code, but work how you want. I tested it in Excel and it seems to be working like a charm.

Comment: Not a problem! Sorry I didn't take the time to work it out yesterday, but glad it's working for you now!

Comment: Also, do you mind selecting this as the answer since it worked for you? Just for future reference if someone comes to the page.

Comment: what if i need a msgbox if it has a duplicated data?!

Comment: By duplicated do you mean duplicated within the same column, or within the same row?

Comment: I updated the answer. Towards the bottom you can see the section I made that checks for a duplicate in column A. Tested in Excel and it works for me.

Comment: Acctually it has a problem, =/ it still inserting the duplicated value.

Comment: Didn't know you wanted to STOP the insert if there was a duplicate, thought you just wanted to display the message box. I fixed the answer and it worked for me in Excel.